# Selenium NoSuchElement exception is still being thrown in a try block

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use try and except to make sure that the testing script keep running even when a exception is thrown, but I have been stuck at a problem for a couple of days. Here's the problem, the "NoSuchElementException" is still being thrown even in a try block, the code and screen shot are attached below.

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

```
    try:         
        invalid = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Maintain Agency']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Error detected")
    else:
        print("Nothing went wrong")
```

Here is the link to the screen shot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK3XS.png

Comment: how did you import the exception ?

Comment: Two things might be happening your element might actually not be found either has a wrong css selector or the element is in an iframe. Or page load is taking a while so use webdriver wait and wait for the presence of element.

Comment: OPS  questiom is the exception is thrown  even though it is inside try except

Comment: I do not see any issue. The fact you are wrapping your code into try block does not mean it won't be throwing exception. The idea of try block is to catch exceptions that the code throws. What is printed out to the console?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for answering my question. The idea is to use "try" to prevent the code from throwing exceptions so that the code can continue to run and test other parts of the application.

Comment: To answer PDHide's question, here's how I imported the exception from "selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException"

Comment: To answer @AlexeyR., nothing is printed in the console, for the details, please have a look at the picture in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK3XS.png. I just don't want the code stops running when the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check this page out:
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-factory-in-selenium/

This is likely happening because the page is not properly loaded at the time of searching for the element. You may need to explicitly use a wait statement.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a wait like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(WEBSITE_URL)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Maintain Agency']"))
)
```